# template class that manages both a vector of pointers and a vector of objects

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have two template class that are very similar: one manages a vector of T* objects
and does things to these pointers, another manages a vector of T objects and does the same thing to these objects.

Is there some way I can have a single class that manages either a list of pointers or a list of objects?

Comment: Make objects that contain pointers?  ;-)  In all seriousness, `std::vector<>` does that, because it doesn't really care what it's holding as long as it meets certain criteria.  Why can't you use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use a [template specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html):

First, declare the class as you would normally:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
     ...
};
```

Then declare a specialization for pointer types:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo<T*>
{
    //re-define any methods you want to be different for the pointer implementation.
};
```

The class can then be used normally, but if the template parameter is a pointer type, it will use the `T*` implementation:

```
Foo<Bar> fooBar; //uses the default implementation
Foo<Bar*> fooPbar; //uses the specialized implementation
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Interact with the members of your `vector` via a helper functor that turns `T&` into `T*` in the value case.  Any other behavior differences can be similarly factored into traits/helper types and handled similarly.

Take the functor as an additional `template` parameter to your `template`.  Possibly hide it by having two public `template`s that pass the appropriate helper functor to the implementation `template`.

In extremely simple cases, you could do away with the functor, and just use overloading on pointers vs references.

Comment: Thanks, Yakk. This approach would work too, but since each class is a thin wrapper around std::vector, it would be more trouble than it is worth in this case.